Can husband teach wife forcefully?
1)I feel i read somewhere that one should not shake another person's shraddha or faith/belief..is it mentioned in Gita?
2)Can husband teach religion to his wife without wife asking for teaching..for example: Suppose my wife is Christian can I tech her Bhagavad gita without her interest just to bring her to my religion or to give her high knowledge. Are there any instances in scriptures where husband taught his wife without her asking?
Please quote references for your answers..

You are basically talking about evangelism. In the past, Abrahamics would marry non-believibg women (by hook or crook) & then evangelise them in order to convert her community.  What you are talking sounds just like that. Evangelism isn't supported by any recognised Hindu denomination other than the Arya Samaj, because Hindu scriptures strongly present the religion as a ethnocentric one.

@অনু indeed and I don't think forceful teaching is mentioned anywhere.
